# Why my test video ads not working on Android but working on editor?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityads

The ads test running on the editor, but not after building to android.
When in editor mode the test running like this

[Video ads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zu2xq.png)

as you can see the test mode also enable test mode on those services and the dashboard at Unity.
I'm using Unity monetization from the asset store with v 3.4.6.
This is my script :

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Advertisements;

public class UnityAds : MonoBehaviour, IUnityAdsListener
{

    [Header("Ads Stuff")]
    public string Google_ID = "******";
    bool testMode = true;
    public string myPlacement = "rewardedVideo";

    void Awake()
    {
        Advertisement.AddListener(this);
        Advertisement.Initialize(Google_ID, testMode);
    }

    // calling when player Death
    public void DisplayVideoAds()
    {
        StartCoroutine(ShowRewardedVideo());
        Debug.Log("Test Mode activate");
    }
#if UNITY_ANDROID|| UNITY_IOS
    public IEnumerator ShowRewardedVideo()
    {
        // Check if UnityAds ready before calling Show method:
        while (!Advertisement.IsReady())
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        }
        Advertisement.Show();

    }
#endif

    // Implement IUnityAdsListener interface methods:
    public void OnUnityAdsDidFinish(string placementId, ShowResult showResult)
    {
        // Define conditional logic for each ad completion status:
        if (showResult == ShowResult.Finished)
        {
            // Reward the user for watching the ad to completion.
            Debug.LogWarning("You got A 2x Reward !!");
        }
        else if (showResult == ShowResult.Skipped)
        {
            // Do not reward the user for skipping the ad.
            Debug.LogWarning("You  got A Min Reward !!");
        }
        else if (showResult == ShowResult.Failed)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("The ad did not finish due to an error.");
        }
    }

    public void OnUnityAdsReady(string placementId)
    {
        // If the ready Placement is rewarded, show the ad:
        if (placementId == myPlacement)
        {

            // Optional actions to take when the placement becomes ready(For example, enable the rewarded ads button)
        }
    }

    public void OnUnityAdsDidError(string message)
    {
        // Log the error.
    }

    public void OnUnityAdsDidStart(string placementId)
    {
        // Optional actions to take when the end-users triggers an ad.
    }

    // When the object that subscribes to ad events is destroyed, remove the listener:
    public void OnDestroy()
    {
        Advertisement.RemoveListener(this);
    }
}
```

I don't have a clue what happened but nothing show error on Debug :

[On Debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2vw5.png)

and last I have warning like this
`Please consider upgrading to the Packman Distribution of the Unity Ads SDK.  The Asset Store distribution will no longer be supported after Unity 2018.3`

is that cause not working on android? have I must publish a beta app on google play store first for the test?

Comment: I am facing the same issue but couldn't find any solution yet